# How to delete duplicate in the below scenario using SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

How to delete the duplicate.Here I want to keep only the distinct records (records)

```
ID          LAST_MODIFIED_DATE      rn
44849691    2019-01-29 00:00:09.000 1
44849691    2019-01-29 00:31:30.000 2
44849691    2019-01-29 00:31:30.000 2
44849691    2019-01-29 00:31:30.000 2
44849691    2019-01-29 00:31:30.000 2
44849691    2019-01-29 00:31:30.000 2
44849691    2019-01-29 00:31:30.000 2
44849691    2019-01-29 00:31:30.000 2
44849691    2019-01-29 00:31:30.000 2
44849691    2019-01-29 00:31:30.000 2
44849691    2019-01-29 00:31:30.000 2
44849691    2019-01-29 00:31:30.000 2
```

using the **RANK** **Partition**  function

Comment: What have you tried?  Check into Row_Number and partition By

Comment: What is the structure of your data? I'm guessing since you already have a `rn`, you're already going some sort of window function. Just adjust it so the records you want to keep are `rn=1` and delete the rest.

Comment: If you want to delete all of the duplicated records, just change your `RANK...OVER...` to a `ROW_NUMBER() OVER....`. Then delete anything not 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `ROW_NUMBER()` window function instead of `RANK()`. Query that in a CTE, then simply `DELETE` records from the CTE. This will fall back into your actual table.

```
; WITH cte1 AS (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY ID, LAST_MODIFIED_DATE ORDER BY ( SELECT NULL ) ) AS rn
    FROM t1 
) 
DELETE FROM cte1 WHERE rn > 1 ;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=0b1e4bba4577837cf7c9cedbd26e3e36

Keep in mind that if you delete a lot of records, you will significantly grow your log and you will need to rebuild any indexes you have.

If you are limited on space, Gordon's answer of just selecting into a new table would be the best. It would really depend on what the rest of the table looks like.

How many rows are we working with? And are there any indexes on the data?

***EDIT NOTE:** I changed my `ROW_NUMBER()` function to `ORDER BY ( SELECT NULL )` instead of an actual field. In this case, we don't seem to care what the ordering will be since we're looking for duplicates.*

**EDIT 2:**

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=1f3eb371dbe1cfa84291e5aaa566cc76

That link demonstrates having an additional column which would prevent us from having truly duplicated rows. But we are still able to delete records based on `ID` and `LAST_MODIFIED_DATE`. However, note that the rows that are considered "duplicates" will be somewhat arbitrary unless you specify another field in the `ORDER BY ....`.

Answer (score 1):

You have lots of duplicates.  How about just creating a new table?

```
select distinct t.*
into distinct_t
from t;
```

You can then re-insert the data if you want:

```
truncate table t;

insert into t
    select * from distinct_t;
```

Comment: Thanks.Is there any way using Rank partition function

Comment: @user1254579 Not with the way you currently seem to be using `RANK()`.

Comment: @user1254579 . . . On a large table, this is probably much more efficient.